# Camera animation plays automatically?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**what I am trying to do:** I have an animation for the camera that is supposed to play when I click on the Create button, however instead of waiting for me to click the button, the camera animation plays right away. 
I have disabled "Play Automatically" however the problem still occurs.
Below are the animation components:

[image]

Here is the code within OnGUI() to check when the button is pressed :

```
//if the create button is pressed
if (GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width * createbuttonPos.x, Screen.height * createbuttonPos.y, Screen.width * buttonSize.x, Screen.height * buttonSize.y), createButton)) {

                                cam.animation.Play ("CreateCharacterCameraMovement");
                                base1 = false;

                        }
```

Main Camera Animation Controller
[image]

Comment: Can you also post your Main Camera Animation Controller? I suspect that it has the CreateCharacter animation as the default state.

Comment: I believe the second image is what you're after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second image is part of [Mecanim](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MecanimAnimationSystem.html). The orange block is the default animation state. This is the new way of doing animation, but you can still use the legacy way. You should be able to remove the Animator component. If that does cause errors, you can just delete the default animation state (select the orange block and hit delete on your keyboard.)

Alternatively, if you would like to use Mecanim instead of the legacy system, you can remove the Animation component. Then in the Animator window, Right click and add a new state. Right click that state and set it to default (insure that in the inspector it has no animation clip set.) Then you can make a transition to a state that has your animation clip. (you can right click a state and add a transition.)

You will then want to add a parameter (bottom left hand corner of the Animator window, click the +) add a trigger type (this a bool that is true for the one frame you set it, essentially.)

Next you need to click on the transition and change it to use the new trigger you created.

Lastly, you can play the animation with a call to [SetTrigger](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetTrigger.html) in your code.

You will also want to ensure there is a transition from the animation state back to the default state for once it finishes playing.